# Matching "IN" a CTE

Tags: sql, oracle

Probably a really easy one for all you SQL experts out there.

I'm trying to use a CTE as follows:

```
WITH MyCTE AS
    (
    SELECT TABLE_A.VALUE
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE TABLE_A.DELETED IS NULL
    )
SELECT
    TABLE_B.ID
FROM
    TABLE_B,
    MyCTE
WHERE
    TABLE_B.VALUE IN MyCTE -- This doesn't work
```

You can see what I'm trying to do. Basically instead of listing out values `IN ('a','b','c')` etc, I just want to use the output of the CTE to define the list.

I guess that using the name of the CTE alone is not valid, and I'd need to specify a column name somewhere. But where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
WITH MyCTE AS
    (
    SELECT TABLE_A.VALUE
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE TABLE_A.DELETED IS NULL
    )
SELECT TABLE_B.ID
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE TABLE_B.VALUE IN (SELECT Value FROM MyCTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another two options:

Join:

```
WITH mycte
     AS (SELECT a.VALUE
           FROM table_a a
          WHERE a.deleted IS NULL)
SELECT DISTINCT b.id
  FROM table_b b JOIN mycte m ON m.VALUE = b.VALUE;
```

Skip CTE completely:

```
SELECT b.id
  FROM table_b b
 WHERE b.VALUE IN (SELECT a.VALUE                 --> this is CTE
                     FROM table_a a
                    WHERE a.deleted IS NULL)
```

Comment: First one is not equivalent. `JOIN` could produce duplicates whereas `IN` could not

Comment: Aha. In this case, `distinct` would help. Thank you, @Lukasz.